# How to install mysqlsla on windows server 2008?

Tags: mysql, windows, perl

I want to install mysqlsla on the windows server 2008.

I have installed strawberryPerl.

But the "make" command failed after "perl Makefile.PL" run successfully.

The following is the error

How can i install it ?

```
C:\Users\I301671\Desktop\Software\mysqlsla-2.03>perl Makefile.PL
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for mysqlsla
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
C:\Users\I301671\Desktop\Software\mysqlsla-2.03>make
to undefined at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 1183.
make: *** [pm_to_blib] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to build the script, there's a ready to use version at http://hackmysql.com/scripts/mysqlsla. Unfortunately I've tested in on strawberry perl and it tries to read environment variables that don't exist on Windows so it may not work for you.

Comment: This link is broken.  Do you have an up-to-date one?